# Set minimum width to a resizable frame in a frameset in html

Tags: html

I have a frameset like below in the code. I want to set minimum width for the frame "frmMView". Frame "frmMView" is resizable, but it should be resizable only to a minimum value.

```
<frameset ID=frmDefault name=frmDefault COLS="250, *" BORDER=1 FRAMEBORDER=1> 
     <frameset ID=frmHeader name=frmHeader ROWS="400,18" BORDER=0 FRAMEBORDER=0 FRAMESPACING=0>                        
      <frame ID=frmMView name=frmMView SCROLLING="auto" SRC="Menu.htm" width="100">              
          <frame ID=frmMSearch name=frmMSearch SCROLLING="no" SRC="Search.html">                                                        
    </frameset>
    <frameset ID=frmDetail name=frmDetail ROWS="0, *" BORDER=0 FRAMEBORDER=0 FRAMESPACING=0>
          ........
          ........
    </frameset>
</frameset>
```

I tried giving minimum width "min-width" to the frame. And also tried adding in css below configuration.

```
.container {
    min-width : 100Px;
    width : 100px;
    width: auto !important;    
}
```

But it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I hope you solved this because you asked this two years ago, but you never included a class in the tag since that's how you wrote your CSS. Also, setting a min-width as the same as a fixed width is redundant since the width won't change.

```
<frame ID=frmMView class="container" name=frmMView SCROLLING="auto" SRC="Menu.htm" width="100">
```